# How to extract a solution from simplex method's tableu while non-stack variables are non-basic?

Tags: linear-programming, simplex-method

Take a look at the following simplex tableu:

[image]

The pivot element is at (1,1) with a value of 2. Eliminating other rows I get the next tableu:
[image]

That is the last step since there is no negative values in the last row, so it's time to extract the solution.

I read from many sources that in order to extract solutions for $X_i$ variables you need to compute $X_i=\frac{b_i}{x_i}$ ($X_i$ is a solution, $x_i$ is a value in the tableu) for variables that are basic, while solution for variables that are non-basic is zero. And often it is the case.

But that is not the case for my tableu.
Here you can see that $x_2,s_1,s_3$ are basic variables. So solution for $x_1$ should be zero, right?

Even though the $x_1$ is non-basic variable, I can solve for it from the first equation (the first tableu row):
$$
4x_1+s_1+s_2=8
$$
Having slack variables as zeros, I get $x_1=2$.
Substituting $x_1$ into the second equation (the second row in the tableu):
$$
-x_1+2x_2+s_2=4
$$
I solve for $x_2$ and get $x_2=3$. Which is the correct result.

To confirm that, I solved the linear programming problem using graphical method and got the result $X=(2,3)$:
[image]

So $x_1$ has a non zero solution even though it was non-basic variable. What then is the algorithm for extracting the solution from the tableu above? Having written a program, how should it read the solution from the tableu?

Comment: At the simplex method you usually  add *artificial variables* if you have $\geq$ constraints. At the start the 3. constraint is $-x_1-x_2\leq -4$ The RHS has to be non-negative. Multiplying the constraint by (-1): $x_1+x_2\geq 4$ Now we add a surplus variable and a slack variable to obtain an equality:  $x_1+x_2+s_3+a_1=4$. The initial solution is $(x_1,x_2,x_3,s_1,s_2,s_3,a_1)=(0,0,0,4,4,0,4)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pivot you divide the pivot row by the pivot entry, so the pivot entry becomes $1$. The nonbasic variables are indeed $0$ in the basic solution, the basic variables are $s_1=8$, $x_2=2$, $s_3=−2$.

However, this is not a feasible solution because negative values are not allowed. You would normally use a Phase I to make the basic solution feasible before starting Phase II to make it optimal. There are several ways of organizing this: consult your textbook.